# ethernet not working

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, cable

i wanted to know how do i setup an ethernet connection on a laptop,my isp gave me a telephone like cable which fits the ethernet port. i guess its the ethernet cable. when i connect it, nothing happens on the pc the ethernet card(realtek pcie gbe family controller) says cable not plugged in. i am using wired connection for first time.the system is completely stable with softwares .the drivers are also automatically updated through a manufacturer installed update system. the isp says there must be some sort of light on the port. whats the problem? how do get it working. .....the isp gave along cable which goes to the neighbouring buildings and continues just like analog cable connections. no other hardware given the card is enabled but it does not detect the cable.also i see no light on the ethernet port.

Comment: not enough info, the other end of the cable connects to a modem-router, what brand of modem?, was the modem set up and connected properly?, the isp should offer competent help with this issue since they make a profit from your monthly donation to them. we need more info to help, use the edit feature to modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

got the connection working.
the ethernet cable was faulty, the isp replaced it and everything worked.
BTW, thans for the answers

Answer (score 0):

**What steps have you followed thus far?** Also, can you verify that both the **router**, and/or **modem** are plugged in?

In order to troubleshoot a physical connection to a router (modem -> router):
 - Verify that green status light is appearing. If not, the unit is not receiving power.
 - Verify that your **router** is connected to the **modem** with an Ethernet cable (Cat5/6). Ensure that it is connected to the WAN port (will be labeled)

With regards to the connection between your **router**, and the **laptop** ensure that the cable is plugged into a port # 1-x (not WAN).

So:

- Modem -- Router (WAN port)
- Router -- laptop (#x)

Wired support should be enabled by default. If not, you can edit your adapter settings in:

- Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Edit Adapter Settings